# Error: "User has no Google Analytics account data"...while there is

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics Spreadsheet add-on but I have the following issue:

I can't connect my GA4 property to it. I always have this as an error:

"Error: User has no Google Analytics account data"...while I'm the admin of my own property.

And as UA will soon be Out Of Date, I don't want to go back to it!

Thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

> Error: User has no Google Analytics account data

Means exactly that the user you have authorized with does not have access to any **Universal analytics** accounts.  AS the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) only works with UA analytics not GA4 it cant see your analytics account.

You need to wait until the add-on is upgraded to Ga4.